# Let $\frak{g}$ a nilpotent Lie álgebra. Prove that there is an ideal $\frak{h}\subseteq\frak{g}$ such that $\dim(\frak{g}) = \dim(\frak{h}) + 1$

Tags: lie-algebras

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Let $\frak{g}$ a nilpotent Lie álgebra. Prove that there is an ideal 
$\frak{h}\subseteq\frak{g}$ such that $\dim(\frak{g}) = \dim(\frak{h}) + 1$

Comment: 1) It's false for $\mathfrak{g}=\{0\}$ which is nilpotent. 2) It's true for every non-perfect Lie algebra (and hence every nonzero nilpotent Lie algebra): any hyperplane containing $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ works (this is user466747's argument).

Comment: I can't do "Lie álgebra" on my keyboard directly, looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the quotient $\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ and note that any codimension 1 subspace is an ideal since this Lie algebra is abelian. Also note that $\mathfrak{g} \neq [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ since $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent.